# How to right align kendo grid numeric field column header?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid. All my column headers are left aligned. I want the column headers having numeric data to be right aligned.Can anyone suggest anything ?

Answer (score 4):

There's already a configuration setting for that.
[columns.headerAttributes](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.headerAttributes)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`columns.headerTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.headerTemplate) property:

```
headerTemplate: kendo.template("<div class='header-right'>ColumnName</div>")
```

With `header-right` being:

```
.header-right {
    text-align: right
}
```

[Working demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/exIJA).

Cons:

- You will have to set this template property to all your numeric columns;
- You will have to set the column's name inside the template.

**UPDATE**

Found simple way of doing this with the following function:

```
var tmpl = function() {
    return kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html())({ columnName: this.toString() });
};
```

This function just calls `kendo.template` and returns its results, passing an object to it with the column's name. It is used in the `columns` property like this:

```
{ field: "age", headerTemplate: tmpl.bind("Age") }
```

It becomes more *elegant* and readable in my opinion, and actually doens't differ so much from the common way to set the column title, as it would be set as `title: "Age"` after all.

And the template:

```
<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class='header-right'>#:columnName#</div>
</script>
```

[Working demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UGiRo).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
#my-grid .k-grid-header .k-header {
   text-align: right;
}
```